# Associate current_user by a controller in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, controller, associations

I'm trying to associate a `current_user.id` to a `@patient.medic_id` via a controller.

I try this in my controller:

```
def create
    #  @patient = Patient.new(patient_params)
    @patient = current_user.patients.build(patient_params[:medic_id => current_user.id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @patient.save
        format.html { redirect_to @patient, notice: 'Patient was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @patient }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @patient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This will automatically fill `medic_id` in the view with the `current_user.id`, but when I submit the form active record doesn't save the others parameters for patient like `name`, `last_name`, `age`, `blood_type`, etc.

This is my model /`medic.rb` (devise - user)

```
class Medic < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :patients
end
```

This is my model /`patient.rb`

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :medic
end
```

**And I need a way to call all registers (patients) from a `medic-user`, to a `show` view; what it is the best way to do this?**

Thanks for the help.

Comment: try current_user.patients.build(patient_params.merge({:medic_id => current_user.id}))

Comment: thank you, it work! I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem when you create a patient:

```
medic_id = {medic_id: current_user.id}
current_user.patients.build(patient_params.merge(medic_id))
```

Assuming you have `@medic` in your `show` action, to get all patients of a `medic-user`:

```
@patients = @medic.patients
```

And in your `show` view, you can access `@patients` as an array.